# Google Maps won't span vertically

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this code executed when a marker is clicked. All works fine except that the map won't span on vertical(it does span on horizontal)

this is my code(javascript)

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infoBox.setContent('<div class="info_details">'+this.image+' <h2>'+this.title+'</h2> <div class="prop_details">'+this.type+' for '+this.type2+' - '+this.price+'</div>' );
   infoBox.open(map, this);    
   map.setCenter(this.position);      
   map.panBy(380,110);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `disableAutoPan`-option of the infoBox to `true`, otherwise the call of `panBy()` will compete with the automatic panning of the infoBox.